# Streams - Filter all not throwing exception

Tags: java, list, exception, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a stream of Reports and I have a method that checks if the user has rights to read each report. This method will throw an exception if the user doesn't have the rights

```
checkReadAuthorization(Report report) throw AccessViolationException;
```

Is there a way to filter out all Reports for which this method throws an exception? Something like:

```
reports.stream()
.filterThrowingException(this::checkReadAuthorization);
```

---

Now I have a function which returns true or false if the exception is thrown but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this

```
private boolean checkAuthorization(Report report) {
    try {
        checkReadAuthorization(report);
        return true;
    } catch(AccessViolationException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then I used it in a filter like this

```
return dossiers.stream()
    .filter(this::checkAuthorization)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The better way would be to refactor the checkReadAuthorization so that it returns something (a boolean for example) instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like "`filterThrowingException`" in the current Stream-API. You can do only to make a decision to keep or filter out the `Report` using `try-catch` inside the `Stream::filter`:

```
List<Report> filtered = list.stream().filter(report -> {
    try {
        this.checkAuthorization(report);
    } catch (AccessViolationException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Personally, I recommend changing the interface of the method `checkReadAuthorization` to return `boolean` indicating whether the input is valid or not.

```
private boolean checkReadAuthorization(Report report) { /* ... */ }
```

this result can be used as a predicate in the filter.

```
List<Report> filtered = list.stream()
                            .filter(this::checkReadAuthorization)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Summary: Better change the design of the validation classes and methods instead of trying Stream-API to adapt what is not optimal.

Comment: Also, this is a good practice as it avoids a multi-line lambda expression.

Comment: I think this is good enough. Anyway If you are using an external function you cannot change it. I think it would be a good thing to add to the streams library

Answer (score 0):

I would swap `checkReadAuthorization` and `checkAuthorization`:

```
private boolean checkAuthorization(Report report) 
{
    // put here the logic that checks for authorization, but without throwing exception
}

void checkReadAuthorization(Report report) throw AccessViolationException
{
    if (!checkAuthorization(report)) {
        throw new AccessViolationException ();
    }
}
```

This way you don't use an exception as a condition.